# How is years distance measured?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, calculate

> Narated By Al-Abbas ibn AbdulMuttalib : I was sitting in al-Batha with
>   a company among whom the Apostle of Allah (pbuh) was sitting, when a
>   cloud passed above them.
>
> The Apostle of Allah (pbuh) looked at it and said: What do you call
>   this? They said: Sahab.
>
> He said: And muzn? They said: And muzn. He said: And anan? They said:
>   And anan. AbuDawud said: I am not quite confident about the word anan.
>   He asked: Do you know the distance between Heaven and Earth? They
>   replied: We do not know. He then said: The **distance between them is
>   seventy-one, seventy-two, or seventy-three years**. The heaven which is
>   above it is at a similar distance (going on till he counted seven
>   heavens). Above the seventh heaven there is a sea, the distance
>   between whose surface and bottom is like that between one heaven and
>   the next. Above that there are eight mountain goats the distance
>   between whose hoofs and haunches is like the distance between one
>   heaven and the next. Then Allah, the Blessed and the Exalted, is above
>   that.

**Abu Dawud Book 035, Hadith Number 4705**

This hadith mention something call years distance. How does one measure years distance?
Is it the distance a camel travels in year?

Comment: It's good to know that the word seven; seventy; seven hundred; seventy thousand (I.e the word seven) is a word in arabic and the semetic languages an expression in many cases and not literally mean 7. see lisan al-arab  http://www.baheth.info/all.jsp?term=%D8%B3%D8%A8%D8%B9

Answer (score 2):

The Hadith you mentioned is quoted in many Hadith Collections with small differences in the narrator chain (Sunan Abi Dawod, Sunan ibn Majah, Jami' at-Tirmdhi etc.) and many scholars have qualified it as dai'f/weak among them al-Albani and ibn al-Jawzy and many have qualified it as hassan or sahih among them al-Hakim, ibn al-Qayim and at-Tirmidhi (hassan gharyb).

Al-Bukhari said that the rawy/narrator Abdullah ibn O'mayra doesn't seem to have met al-Ahnaf ibn Qays. And all the Versions of this Hadith have in it the Rawy Sammak ibn Harb, who seems to be unknown!

According to the [following](http://www.sonnaonline.com/DisplayExplanation.aspx?ExplainId=84998&HadithID=5350) interpretation of this hadith:

It seems that there's a more known (or famous) Hadith which quotes a 500 years walk (see [here](http://sunnah.com/urn/678930), [here](http://sunnah.com/urn/680080) and [here](http://sunnah.com/urn/678460))! So the interpreter of the Hadith explains the numbers just as a device to show that it is a very long time. An other possible interpretation is that this duration depends on the strength of the Malak who's crossing the distance between the heavens.

And Allah know best

Answer (score -1):

The **year** here means: 12 months of time, one pass of the moon (1 month) is about 2153025kms, so 25836300kms for 12 months means 1 year.

The first heaven is in a distance about 25836300kms, 1 AU (astromical unit) is 149597870kms, this means the first heaven is 0.172 AU away. The magnetic field of earth is about the same distance. The earth ends there.

Calculate so on.

Comment: but i am not sure

Comment: Being not sure is a bad statement when it comes to answers, as we would like evidenced answers here as you may know (see [answer]).