# Dreams are 1/46 of Prophethood; what are the remaining 45/46?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, dream, scripture

I've read this verse several times that dreams are 1/46 part of Prophethood. 
Ṣaḥīḥ al-Bukhārī 6614, Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 2263

What exactly does this mean in relation to the number 46, or more precisely, what is the remaining 45/46?

Comment: Another one I have read in a Hadith is Ilham.

Comment: What is ilham...?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39805/what-is-the-difference-between-wahi-and-ilham

Comment: Most likely the matter is similar to https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33150/13438. Further more to answer this one needs to be a prophet or angel or have authentic reports from a prophet.

Answer (score 1):

Prophet Muhammad (SAW) did not tell us about the other 46 qualities of a Prophet, it could be Angel Jibreel coming, etc, etc, but we do not know. Hope this helps.

And Allah knows best.

Comment: Exactly. Allah knows best.